# How can i echo image size in PHP?

Tags: php

I try to put image size in image src tag, but it still does not work. The image can be displayed fine.

```
<?php
$files = glob("uploads/*.*");

echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";

for ($row=1; $row <= 4; $row++) { 
    echo "<tr> \n";
    for ($col=1; $col<=4; $col++) { 

       $f=$f+1;
       $getfile = $files[$f]; 
       echo "<td>";
       echo "<img src=$getfile  > ";
       echo "</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You want to set height and width of an image? That is HTML 1.0, the very basic of everything. https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_img_width.asp

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $row['getfile']?>" height="130" width="150" /> ?

Comment: Use [getimagesize()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get the dimensions of an image (along with some other info)

Comment: If you want to customise the size of an image you can use the style attribute e.g. `style="width: ....; height: ..."` . This is preferred to using the height and width attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getimagesize() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php to fetch image size

```
<?php 
    $files = glob("uploads/*.*");
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";

    for ($row=1; $row <= 4; $row++) {
        echo "<tr> \n";
        for ($col=1; $col<=4; $col++) {

            $f=$f+1;
            $getfile = $files[$f];
            $size = getimagesize($getfile);
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<img src=$getfile  $size[3]> ";
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: This is the same thing as without. The image will be displayed in full size.

Comment: Need quotes round the image file name in the img tag.

Comment: @NigelRen:It's not necessary, i have tested code in my local

Answer (score 0):

PHP Function filesize will hep you here

```
echo  filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: I think OP is looking for dimensions rather than filesize. But I could be wrong.

Comment: hi, thanks i have found the solution, echo '<img src="'.$gefile.'" width="200" height="200" />';